# Add Buttons and a Textblock With Each Binded Image

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm developing an UWP app and i'm trying to add two buttons and a textblock for each image that binded.

I'm binding the images in XAML like this; (Updated with the full code)

```
   <GridView Name="display"
              Margin="30,100,30,5"
              Foreground="#FFFFFF"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
              ItemClick="display_ItemClick"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}">

        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image Width="240"
                           Height="240"
                           Source="{Binding Path=Image}" />

                    <StackPanel Name="buttonPanel" 
                                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                Margin="0,-45,10,0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button Name="button_minus" 
                                Content="-" 
                                Width="40" 
                                Height="30" 
                                Click="eksi_click" 
                                FontWeight="Bold">
                            <Button.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/btn2.png" Stretch="Fill" />
                            </Button.Background>
                        </Button>
                        <Border Background="White" CornerRadius="10" Height="30">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="popupNumber"
                                       Width="50"
                                       Height="25"
                                       Margin="0,6,0,0"
                                       Text="{Binding Path=numberOfCopy}"
                                       TextAlignment="Center">
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                        <Button Name="button_plus" Content="+" Width="40" Height="30" Click="artı_Click" FontWeight="Bold">
                            <Button.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/btn2.png" Stretch="Fill" />
                            </Button.Background>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>


                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

I added a stackpanel that contains the Buton-TextBlock-Button format in the seciton of code that i commented out. When i do this, some buttons are not working and i don't actually know is it the best way to do my task.

When i launch the program, some buttons are not available to click. I can see them in the UI but i can't click them. The most awkward thing is only in a specific area on the UI, buttons are unavailable.

My click events are just fine, i have some binding issues, i am wondering is it the proper way to to something like that. Is it the way i am using causes the binding problem?

In in each TextBlock the values should be different for each image and i can't access buttons and textblocks in .cs file because they are in DataTemplate. So i might be doing this in a wrong way.

So do you have any solutions for adding buttons and textblocks for each binded image in Datatemplate? I'm not sure my way is the best way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to post your button/textblock code as well. Given your explanation, I don't see why there should be any problem. Also please explain what you meant with "When I do this, some buttons are not working..:". Why are they not working? What do you expect out of them?

Comment: Updated question with more details, thanks for reply.

Comment: I can't see any problem at first sight. Only thing that catches my attention is the button binding to the "numberOfCopy" property. Is that name a typo? Is it a property? Is it public? (camel case is usually used for private variables which wont let you bind to them from the UI).

Comment: `private List<sadeimage> imagelist;` this is my list and sadeimage class has `public int numberOfCopy { get; set; }` in it. I started to think the problem is refreshing the value after binding it. And this is how i change the variable;  imagelist[selectedIndex].numberOfCopy++;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("numberOfCopy");

Comment: I just copied your gridview to a new project and then added events. created sample data and bound the data to grid view. Every button is working fine. So there is no problem with your grid view or clicking. Only difference from mine to yours is my grid view is wrapped just with a Grid that comes up by default. So in your case check the xaml for wrapped control.